# implement android:src="@drawable/image" programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-imageview, android-button

I am trying to set the foreground image on an image button. After some research, I came across this code sample:

```
<ImageButton android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
```

My query is how to actually implement android:src in code.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Try this:

```
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.newimage);
```

where `newimage` is the image name in *drawable* folder.

**EDITED**
try this:

```
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

where *bm* is bitmap extracted from server.

**EDITED AGAIN**
I see you receive a Drawable; well, do this:

```
normalImage = Drawable.createFromStream(code);
Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable)normalImage).getBitmap();
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: Thanks alot.. however, I am getting the image from the server and not storing it in drawable folder, is there any way of achieving this??

Comment: This is super Marco, however I am only limited to drawables..this is the design specification..I can not use bitmaps

Comment: @user788511: if you're limited to drawables, what does your server returns you?

Comment: the server returns image which is converted to drawable at runtime

Comment: @user788511: Where do you save that runtime converted image? Which android type is your converted image?

Comment: I implement it like this:normalImage = Drawable.createFromStream(code)

Comment: @user788511: take a look at my edited answer and let me know if this works.

Comment: Marco, thank you for the help, however I receive a BitmapDrawable can not be resolved to a type error!! Is there a remedy?

Comment: @user788511: did you import correct library? Do you have this error at compile-time or at run-time?

Comment: @user788511: use this `import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;`. Anyway if you use Eclipse you can hit CTRL+SHIFT+M over _BitmapDrawable_ and the import is done automatically!

Comment: Marco, I have tried this but still not progressing, is there a way I can convert this drawable to a resource so that I can use setImageResource()?? Thank you for all the help

Comment: @user788511: _still not progressing_ doesn't help us to understand which problem you're facing. Explain better: after you inserted correct import and modified code, what's happening? 1. Do you receive correctly your drawable from server? 2. Is your drawable converted to bitmap?

Comment: I apologize.. After I fix the imports and run the code, the image is not displayed on the foreground as with setImageResource(), it is displayed in the background..

Comment: @user788511: close this question and accept an answer, believe me!! You told us you couldn't set the image and we all told you dozens of methods to do it, helped you with code... and you tell us that yes, your image is shown but in the background... come on, google around or ask another question on SO to know how to show this image in front of your button !!!

Answer (score 15):

Here's what worked for me in setting the **`image:src`** on an **`ImageButton`** programmatically** or through code:

1.Retrieve the image drawable.

```
Drawable tempImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image);
```

2.Get the view.

```
ImageButton tempButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.my_image_button);
```

3.Set the image for the view.

```
tempButton.setImageDrawable(tempImage);
```

Hope this works for you too!

Comment: Very clear! Note, though, that step 1 uses an API that is deprecated as of API Level 22. I replaced it with: ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.my_image).

Answer (score 4):

Hope ths will help you

```
ImageButton button1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);       
button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

Comment: Thanks alot.. however, I am getting the image from the server and not storing it in drawable folder, is there any way of achieving this??

Comment: I think you can make a bitmap object from that image and use button1.img.setImageBitmap(yuorbitmapobject);

Answer (score 3):

**try this::**

```
ImageButton tran_btn_skip;

tran_btn_skip = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap_skip = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                "http://233.129.115.55/MRESC/images/test/skip.png")
                .getContent());
        tran_btn_skip.setImageBitmap(bitmap_skip);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot.. however, I am getting the image from the server and not storing it in drawable folder, is there any way of achieving this??

Comment: by this you can get image from particular url

Comment: This is superb Nik, however I am working with drawables not bitmaps, is there a workaround for this??

Comment: basically it will take any image in bitmap format and set on button. trust me try and vote me

Comment: take any temp url and past in code and try it out but make sure in manifest you need to make Internet permission

Comment: Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap_skip );

Answer (score 2):

One more short variant

```
views.setImageViewResource(R.id.button1, R.drawable.newbutton);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for future searches...
I believe what you are looking for is:

```
imgButton.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```