# how to set imagebutton src in onCreateView?

Tags: android

In my app, I have several `ImageButton`s that are controlled by their respective `StateListDrawable`s. I use them as tab menu at the bottom of the activity to switch fragments. They change states just fine (when pressed, focused, default). Switching of fragments also works okay. However, I don't know how can I make a button be highlighted (for example, use the image set when pressed) when the fragment it represents is currently shown.

I've tried setting the `BackgroundResource`, `ImageDrawable`, `ImageResource` during runtime but I am getting a `NullPointerException` everytime I launch my app.

Here's my log if this helps

```
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.meralco/com.meralco.pms.TestPMSActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at com.meralco.pms.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:19)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:505)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3791)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1624)
05-16 14:15:19.489: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     ... 11 more
```

Here's HomeFragment.xml:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
    ImageButton btn_sin = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.drawable.button_sin);
    btn_sin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pp_sin_1);
    return view;
    }
}
```

home.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"  >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/home_text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/home_text1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/home_text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/home_text2"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/home_text3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/home_text3"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:src="@drawable/phone_portrait_bg_01" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/phone_portrait_bg_02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <fragment class="com.meralco.pms.ButtonsHandler"
        android:id="@+id/titles" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" >
        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/buttons -->
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

ButtonsHandler.java

```
public class ButtonsHandler extends Fragment{   
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttons, container, false);
    }
}
```

buttons.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_sin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:src="@drawable/button_sin"
        android:onClick="buttonClick" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_city"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"

        android:src="@drawable/button_city"
        android:onClick="buttonClick" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_date"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:src="@drawable/button_date"
        android:onClick="buttonClick" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_all"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:src="@drawable/button_all"
        android:onClick="buttonClick" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_help"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:src="@drawable/button_help"
        android:onClick="buttonClick" />

</LinearLayout>
```

TIA!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346864/implement-androidsrc-drawable-image-programatically-in-android

Comment: @simplymoody where is imagebutton in xml

Comment: @Khan on a separate xml for tab menu fragment...`

Comment: i have an idea. i think this is because i'm accessing the tab menu fragment from `HomeFragment`...still doesn't know how to do that. will read that first.

Comment: plz show some more code if u have added in it

Comment: @simplymoody where is button_sin placed?. I can't see it in the xml.

Comment: ^ on the buttons.xml which is used by ButtonsHandler.java

Answer (score 17):

```
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.newimage);
```

Comment: API reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)

Comment: tried it already and didn't work. is this because i'm using fragments?

Comment: In a fragment you probably need to getActivity() so that you have the correct context for accessing resources before you can use them

Answer (score 5):

try this way

```
ImageButton btn_sin = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_sin);
btn_sin.setImageResource(R.drawable.pp_sin_1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to **button_sin** in **HomeFragment** because **HomeFragment** uses **home.xml** layout.

Yo can do the next

```
public class ButtonsHandler extends Fragment{   
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttons, container, false);

        ImageButton btn_sin = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_sin);
        btn_sin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pp_sin_1);

        return 
    }
}
```

Comment: if i do the code above, even if I'm not on `HomeFragment`, `btn_sin` will have `R.drawable.pp_sin_1` as background, right? I want the background be changed only if the fragment it represents is currently showing. otherwise, it will return to its default image...

Comment: @simplymoody. With the code i gave you, the button is inside the Fragment, so if the Fragment is not shown, you won't see the button. Anyway, i don't undestand well your design.

Comment: nope, the buttons are on a separate fragment. i'm dong a single-activity-multiple-fragments implementation. i have two framents, the tab menu and the detail fragment. i just switch fragments on the detail fragment.. thanks anyway..

Comment: @simplymoody. Ok. So you have 2 fragments, HomeFragment and ButtonsHandler, am I allright?.

Answer (score 0):

For connecting a fragment with an activity, look here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity.

So first you connect ButtonsHandler with your activity.Then you create a method in HomeFragment and you just need to call this method from your activity.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with your code

```
   ImageButton btn_sin = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.drawable.button_sin);
```

change this to

```
   ImageButton btn_sin = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_sin);
```

the R.id.button_sin must be your imagebutton id in your layout